# doctrine querybuilder $qb -> expr()-> all

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with Symfony2. I have to list last $nbOpe entities of Entity OpeEntetes. The following script gives me error:

> Blockquote

[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 16 near 'ALL(SELECT FROM': Error: Class 'ALL' is not defined.

> Blockquote

What to do ?

```
public function essai1($nbOpe){
        $in = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('GcRequetesBundle:OpeEntetes','ein')
            ->orderBy('ein.oeNumOpe', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($nbOpe);

$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb
                -> add("select",new Expr\Select(array('res')))
                -> add('from', new Expr\From($qb -> expr()-> all($in -> getDql()), 'res'));
            $query = $qb -> getQuery();
            $result= $query -> getArrayResult();
            return $result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of errors in your code:

- subqueries do no support setMaxResults [Enabling LIMIT resp. setMaxResults on subquery](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3196)
- from field does not support subqueries [Subquery into FROM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2793)
- you have probably misunderstood what the ALL expression means and for what it is used for [For example MySql documentation about ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html)

In any case, the restriction that subqueries do not support the setMaxLimits probably means that you cannot build your code in this way at all. If that isn't a show-stopper for you, then you could try it with the following code for example (easiest would be to just have one query, but I assume you have some reason for doing this in two steps...):

```
    $in = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('ein')
        ->from('GcRequetesBundle:OpeEntetes','ein')
        ->orderBy('ein.oeNumOpe', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults($nbOpe); // this does not affect the result at all

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->add('select', 'ein2');
    $qb->add('from', 'GcRequetesBundle:OpeEntetes ein2');
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->eq('ein2.id', $qb->expr()->any($in->getDql())));
    $query = $qb -> getQuery();
    $result= $query -> getArrayResult();
    return $result;
```

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly, and, indeed, the number of records in the result is not limited to $nbOpe.
My application must therefore be split into two